# Load web page in div with jquery cors issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cors

Is there any other way to load webpage or part of web page to a div when the webpage is a external site?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer1">

</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$('#mainContainer1').load('https://projects.xyz.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa #gadget);
        $('#mainContainer2').load('https://projects.xyz.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa');
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about an iframe (HTML-tag)?

Comment: You could use a server side script to pull the content. PHP has curl but other server side languages use similar methods. Then load the results in your div.

Comment: Iframe cannot pull part of external webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.load()` if the page is on the same domain. `.load()` will load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element (the target page should be on the same domain otherwise you get a CORS restriction).

Or use an iframe which have no restrictions:

```
<iframe src="URL"></iframe>
```

Comment: doesn't the `.load()` function, makes the `Cross Domain` problem?

Comment: assuming domain is external, there will be cors issue.